# using a DSL modem router as a wifi extender

Tags: wireless-networking, dsl-modem

I want to use my DSL modem router as a WIFI extender/access point.  My problem is that I no longer have a phone-line internet connection, so I cant get into the router login page to reconfigure the settings. Can this be done without internet connection?
make ZyXEL and model P-660HW-T1 v3

I have purchased a netgear router modem and 2 netgear wifi extenders, but i want to set up the old router as an access point also.

Comment: Hi ger. This question *might* be answerable if you [edit] your question to state the exact make and model of the modem in question. As it stands, this is unanswerable because every make and model of modem is going to be different.

Comment: make ZyXEL and model P-660HW-T1 v3

Comment: What if you plug a telephone cable in there anyway.

Comment: I have seen a ZyXel that wouldn't let me configure it unless it was plugged into the wall with a telephone cable, very very strange that was. I think maybe it didn't even bring a page up.. Obviously nobody is going to have Internet access the moment they plug it in.. But it may be you need a phone line in there. Nevertheless, try plugging it in anyway even though you lack a phone line (if you have a socket to plug it in!)  and see if it lets you. And call Zyxel. (though I think I called them and they told me to plug it into the phone line.. and I had a phone line).

Comment: maybe you can plug it into a friend/neighbours phone line or else somehow fool it into thinking it is plugged into a phone line..An electronic shop like maplin may have some ideas if it really need sto be fooled into thinking it is plugged into a phone line to be configured.. But if it does it may just be a one off just to get it configured, so try plugging it into a friends.  Though even then it'll be frustrating for you if you have to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your router login page by powering it on, connecting your computer to it (using an ethernet cable for instance) and by entering

```
192.168.1.1
```

in your web browser (it could also be `192.168.0.1`). Make sure that you are not connected to anything else in the meanwhile (other WiFi for instance).

From there, you can configure it as you use to.

However, I'm not at all convinced that you can use it as a signal repeater : you would need a custom firmware for that. But from what I've read, the main alternative firmwares out there (openwrt, dd-wrt) don't support this router.

Comment: You write "You should be able to access your router login page by powering it on, connecting your computer to it (using an ethernet cable for instance) and by entering"  <-- In almost every case you can and should.do so.   But I have encountered a Zyxel modem router  where you couldn't.. There's no good reason for it, but it didn't, I had to have a telephone cable attached to it. I was stuck for quite a while until I realized that.  I don't recall the specifics it's possible it didn't let me even get a web config page up.